# How do I create an AMI image using the AWS Java 2.x SDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I need to programmatically create an AMI image of the EC2 instance that the application is running on. According to the AWS java docs there exists a class called [CreateImageRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/ec2/model/CreateImageRequest.html). I've figured out how to instantiate such an object but i don't know how to execute this request.

I've searched for an example on [the code example github page of the AWS Java 2.x SDK](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code) but unfortunately it doesn't include an example on how to create an AMI image. I've looked at the [Amazon SDK developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/java_ec2_code_examples.html) as well but couldn't find relevant information there either.

This is the code that I have sofar:

```
public String createEC2InstanceAMI(Ec2Client ec2, String name, String instanceId , boolean noReboot) {
    CreateImageRequest imageRequest = CreateImageRequest.builder()
            .instanceId(instanceId)
            .description("The AMI image for " + name)
            .name(name)
            .noReboot(noReboot)
            .build();
    ec2.runInstances(imageRequest); //This breaks.
}
```

I tried creating the request using the method `runInstances` but this requires a `RunInstancesRequest` object. `Ec2Client` doesn't seem to have any other methods that are similar to the `runInstances` method that i could use to create an AMI image request.

How do I create and register an AMI image with the AWS java SDK v2.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ec2.runInstances()` is a method for running (creating) new EC2 instances/servers. Obviously that's not the correct method to call for creating an AMI. I suggest taking a few minutes to look at [the SDK documentation](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/ec2/Ec2Client.html).

The [method you are looking for](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/ec2/Ec2Client.html#createImage(software.amazon.awssdk.services.ec2.model.CreateImageRequest)) would be `ec2.createImage()`.

Comment: pffff I was searching the method list for `AMI` instead of `image`, that's why didn't find it. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.